# COALESCE Vs OR IS NULL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, coalesce, nvl

I would like to know for my scenario, if there are 2 tables:

employee:
`id, city, job_level`

filters:
`city, job_level, some_val`

I have a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   employee e 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM   filters f 
                  WHERE  e.city = COALESCE(f.city, e.city) 
                         AND ( f.job_level IS NULL 
                                OR e.job_level = f.job_level ))
```

If you can see the conditions for both city and job_level work exactly the same way. However, I would like to know which one would perform better. Also, I would like to know the recommended indexes for these tables for such a query.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of coalesce in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't going to really make a difference from a performance perspective.  You have a complicated `WHERE` clause, that already includes an `OR` condition.  This pretty much precludes using an index.

Given what you are doing with the `COALESCE()`, I think `OR IS NULL` is clearer.

If you care about performance, you might consider splitting this into multiple comparisons:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM filters f 
                  WHERE e.city = f.city AND 
                        ( f.job_level IS NULL  OR e.job_level = f.job_level )
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM filters f 
                  WHERE f.city IS NULL AND 
                        ( f.job_level IS NULL  OR e.job_level = f.job_level )
                 )
```

This can at least take advantage of an index on `filters(city, job_level)`.